# In Celery Task Queue, is running tasks in a group any different than multiple asyncs in a loop?

Tags: python, celery, task-queue

Let's say I have a very simple task like this:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def print_page(page):
    with open('path/to/page','w') as f:
        f.write(page)
```

(Please ignore the potential race condition in the above code... this is a simplified example)

My question is whether the following two code samples would produce identical results, or if one is better than the other:

Choice A:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def print_pages(page_generator):
    for page in page_generator:
        print_page.s(page).apply_async()
```

Choice B:

```
@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def print_pages(page_generator):
    g = group(print_page.s(page) for page in page_generator)
    g.apply_async()
```

And in general, I am curious if the above is the correct way to do what I'm doing. Essentially, I have another task that is parses some data and returns a generator which will emit all of the pages of a document. For each page, I want to output it separately.

So, my chain looks something like this (also simplified):

```
chain = fetch.s(url) | parse.s() | print_pages.s()
chain()
```

I think it would make more sense if I could somehow emit the generator inside that chain and for the group there (outside of an actual task). But I am not sure if that is practical or ideal. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first choice seems like the better one.  You have no desire to join the results (given that ignore_result=True) of the fanned-out print_pages tasks so a group adds unnecessary overhead/complexity.  Just invoke the tasks individually as in choice A and you're fine.

Further though, I'd like to note that Python generators will not pickle so you cannot pass them asynchronously to Celery tasks.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Regarding the generators, I have been passing them through a chain and that seems to be working. They are not being passed through the backend, but rather straight through the chain.

Comment: Good info about the non-serialization of chord args.  Thanks.

Comment: One difference is that the loop version needs to acquire and release a connection from the pool at every iteration, whereas the group one will only do it once.

Answer (score 1):

both solution is correct in your case there is no depending in the pages tasks but lets assume you have a task divided in sub tasks and all these subtasks are depedant sequentially in this case you should group it by choosing B

Comment: Aha, so you mean that if I had a chain like this, then option B would be the way to go?:
chain = fetch.s(url) | parse.s() | render_pages.s() | write_pages.s()

Comment: (Assuming that render_pages.s() behaves in the same way as write_pages.s() - just that I would hypothetically pre-render each page before writing and then pass the group of pages to the next stage to be written...)