# When using celery and rabbitmq, is it possible for the queue to get so large that everything locks up?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, task-queue

I am using celery and rabbitmq to do a chain that looks something like this:

```
fetch -> parse -> write pages
```

The `write pages` part issues it's own set of asynchronous tasks to write each individual page in parallel (as described in this other question of mine: [In Celery Task Queue, is running tasks in a group any different than multiple asyncs in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614441/in-celery-task-queue-is-running-tasks-in-a-group-any-different-than-multiple-as/14615919#14615919))

When I run this for a long time, I have observed that it will eventually just stop. It will again if I restart celery, but only after executing another 60 or so tasks and then it stops again.

I have noticed that this happens when the queue size gets up to a little over 400k:

```
fast@build1 ~/dev/content-admin $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
build1.prod2.ec2.cmg.net.celery.pidbox  0
celery  433410
...done.
```

I think that what is happening is that the queue is filling with these "write pages" tasks which wil *add* more items to the queue and then once it's "full", it never gets a chance to execute those newly added tasks.

I have experimented by temporarily modifying the "write pages" task to instantly return (do nothing) and that appears to have cleared the congestion and enabled the output of all ~400,000 pages. However, I am not 100% why that even worked.

Is there an upper limit that is imposed by RabbitMQ or by Celery? And is it based on available memory? Or is it configurable? And finally: How can I manage the tasks better so that this doesn't happen?

Is redis more suited for what I'm doing?

I think if there were more "write page" workers that would help, but I also want to somehow force that the "write page" tasks take precedence.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ performance can degrade if the memory fills up and publishers are avoiding the [flow control](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html). The [RabbitMQ Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) will allow you to more easily diagnose problems. You will want to look for the memory and/or disk high water marks being hit which will help you gauge capacity.