# how to loop over and create multiple django celery tasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have 3 employees and I am trying to create multiple celery tasks like this:

```
for e in employees:
     res1 = escalate.apply_async((e.id), countdown=3)
     print res1.id
```

This should create 3 tasks but it only creates 1.

Each id prints out:
dc553662-283e-46e5-b811-7c1f5ed08d2d
be7043bc-02a1-4641-b8e6-c230bf1d7325
5b88e6cc-8514-4e80-8f4f-eb8b05f3625b

Is there a limitation in celery that doens't allow me to create multiple tasks in this way?  If not, how can I create multiple tasks in a loop?

Comment: How do you know that it is creating only 1 celery task? Could you print `res1.id` after each call?

Comment: I print all of the tasks and each has an id. What does that mean?  How do I make the tasks that have an id, but do not fire?

Comment: You have multiple options. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614441/in-celery-task-queue-is-running-tasks-in-a-group-any-different-than-multiple-as

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those employee ids as a list to the task, iterate over it in "escalate" task and do whatever functionality you intend to. That's how I would have gone with this.